# What is the correct sed (with regex) command to replace this piece of text?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

Im making a script that has to replace a string of text in a file, this piece of text is part fixed and part random.

I've been trying to fix this for quite a while with some Regex tools on the web, but cant figure it out...

The string that needs to be replaced is:

> $mysql_pass = 'password';

Note: 'password' is a random alphanumeric string.

I want to change 'password' (or a random password) to something new, this new password will be generated before and be put in a variable, lets say $pass.

> $mysql_pass = '$pass';

AKA

> $mysql_pass = 'xOaL4c5ETgt0Izm';

Maybe is should use different command, I dont know, but i rather not download other programs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A clean way to do that is to use php itself via the tokenizer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/$mysql_pass = .*/$mysql_pass = '"'$pass'"';/' file
```